# A DATE with the ORACLE - The Time Zone Dilemma. Is it midnight or is there no time?

Tags: oracle

So I'm writing some code trying to convert some oracle dates I got into a different time zone. The issue I'm having is that when the time portion is **00:00:00** I don't now how to determine if it is legitimately midnight or if the date was meant to not include a time.

Currently, I'm making the assumption that if the time is 00:00:00 then the value is just a time-free date, because unfortunately that is sometimes the case, but while statistically small, there is a chance that the date is legitimately midnight so I'm trying to find a better approach with no success.

I can't assume all 00:00:00 are midnight, because if the data was intended to only have a date then converting to most other US time zones would change the date.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Up to the originator of data. If they are leaving empty the time on purpose, you can't possibly know.

Comment: that is unfortunate because the data originators are many, and a few have purposely not included a time. Was hoping there was some oracle voodoo to determine if the time defaulted to 00:00:00 or was was explicitly provided.

Comment: No, there is no magic for this, Oracle makes no distinction. Incidentally, are you sure that all the time values you do have from your many originators are/were appropriate for the time zone you're converting from, and aren't actually in the originators' (various?) time zones? No way to tell that either from the data itself, of course.

Comment: Unless you have really sloppy input data, all of your times should be stored per the timezone of your Database Server. Oracle has a bunch of inbuilt timezone support functions which will perform the conversions for you. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch4datetime.htm#NLSPG004) for documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for other values in the same column to see what the distribution of 00:00:00's is. If all entries are 00:00:00 then the column is definitely dates, if it's roughly 1 in (24*60*60) occurrences then it's definitely times, if it's somewhere in between then you've got a problem.

You could also look for a check constraint to see if times are constrained to be midnight.

You could look at the semantics of the column also -- what does the name tell you?

Comment: thanks, this actually helps with a data analysis i'm working on. However, in this particular case, I already know that sometimes it is a date and sometimes it is meant to include time, something like 20% are missing a time for a column that has the word timestamp in the name.